# Flip View in ipad

Tags: ipad, flip

I am having a button on a view clicking on which next view should open in flip view.

Can anyone help me??

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091789/flip-viewcontroller-only-flips-the-first-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume your view is managed by a view-controller, and so is the view you want to flip-in.

A relatively easy way to do this is to present the new view using presentModalViewController:animated:

```
MyViewController* mvc = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
mvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
mvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController: mvc animated: YES];
```